# Images are getting bigger size while scrolling the listview in android

Tags: android

I am loading an images which comes from server into my listview, Initially they are in some size,but when I scroll the list Images are getting bigger size,I think there is a problem with ImageLoader class which we use to load images into list.

ImageLoader class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    }

//    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {
//            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Log.v("first", "first");
        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            Log.v("second", "second");

        }    
    }

    public void DisplayImg(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap( bitmap, 0,70,70));

            Log.v("first", "first");
        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            Log.v("second", "second");

        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }//Lalit

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if(tag!=null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));

        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels,int width,int height) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

//  public void DisplayImage(String replaceAll, ImageView img) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      
//  }
}
```

The code I use to load images is

```
class Profiles extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


        private Activity context;
       ArrayList<String> Arrlist_companyid,Arrlist_largeimage,Arrlist_desc;
      ImageView ivCompany;                        

    public Profiles(Activity c,int a,ArrayList<String> company_id, ArrayList<String> company_image,ArrayList<String> company_desc){

         super(c,a, company_id);
                this.context=c;                 
                this.Arrlist_companyid = company_id;
                this.Arrlist_largeimage=company_image;
                this.Arrlist_desc=company_desc;



    }

          @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           View v = convertView;
//           LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.inflated_companies, null);
                    ivCompany = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

                    try{
                        imgLoader.DisplayImage( Arrlist_largeimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), ivCompany);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    return v;
        }

//         
 }//closing TaskAdapter
```

Is there anything needs to be changed in my Adapter or ImageLoader to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a nice session
  [about loading bitmaps here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)